# moving object in the screen in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, core-motion, sphero-api

I am knew to **sphero ios sdk**. I would like to know that how could I achieve the movement of object from one point to another in screen of my device while I moving my device from one direction to another using sphero. I have refereed **"StreamingAnimation"** demo project of sphero. I have also refereed other sample projects of sphero ios sdk also but I am not able to get that how could i achieve the movement of object while I am moving my device from one direction to other. Your reply would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

am taking Image to move

> UIImageView*animationImage;
>
> UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
>
> panRecognizer.delegate = self;
>
> [animationImage addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

In Method You Should Implement Like this

```
-(void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{

   CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];

   CGPoint imageViewPosition = animationImage.center;
   imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;

   imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;
    
   animationImage.center = imageViewPosition;

   [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
        
}
```